# Why are the job ads on serverfault all for developers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, careers, advertising

ServerFault is frequented by system administrators.

[careers.serverfault.com](http://careers.serverfault.com) exists, and has job adverts for system administrators and the like.

Yet, all the job ads on the right hand side of ServerFault are for *developers*. Surely there could be a better click-through rate if these job ads were matched up to careers.serverfault.com instead of careers.stackoverflow.com ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is planned, but we're not quite there yet.  [careers.serverfault.com](http://careers.serverfault.com) actually just shows the same jobs as [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.serverfault.com) right now, and thus they show the same job ads.  Eventually we want to either automatically boost sysadmin etc. jobs on serverfault, or allow employers to explicitly select one site to target.

Comment: Is it still planned ?