# Make job ads related to professional system administration on serverfault for the default visitor

Tags: feature-request, advertising, careers

I’m currently a student who aim at becoming a professional system administrator. I hate having full time developer jobs *(from stackoverflow careers)* particularly on serverfault.

Since [there are jobs relevant to professional system administration on stackoverflow careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/100953/administrateur-h-f-serveur-de-calculs-inria) and this site is dedicated to professionals, I would expect to only have such jobs advertised on severfault questions *(or at least they should concern most of the jobs advertised here)*.

For me, the situation is like presenting miller jobs on a baker site.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @mdpc It's not a question but a feature request.

Comment: ok, what is the specific request here?

Comment: @mdpc : I ask to make job ads relevant to system administration for new users on Server Fault *(instead of developers)*. Please vote up this request if you also want this.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't know too terribly in-depth about the specifics, but in a nutshell, it tries to show you the most relevant job listings considering what it knows about you, which includes location, what site you're looking at, and which questions and technologies you seem to be interested in based on what questions you've looked at (see [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/)).

Since you've participated more on Stack Overflow than here, that probably contributes to you seeing programmer job ads - or maybe there just aren't many sysadmin jobs listed in your local area (would the one you linked be considered "local" to you?).  Try a session with no cookies (chrome incognito or similar) to see what it would be showing you when it knows nothing about you aside from location.

To directly address your request - no, we won't specifically prevent programming jobs from showing on Server Fault, because there's a lot of overlap in audience between this site and Stack Overflow, and in some cases (for instance, any of those jobs that say "DevOps") there's overlap in job listings too (and in some cases there just aren't many local jobs to show, so the selection engine needs to work with what it has, and might not show you terribly interesting jobs).

Comment: [related](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6056/203649). The current problem is it still advertise developer jobs most of the time.

Comment: @user2284570 That may be true for you, due to location and lack of local sysadmin jobs - but, again, that's a consequence of what listings are available to show you.  If your complaint is that careers is programming-dominated, I'll refer you to Will's answer on that question - there are specific features in the product to help businesses target sysadmins for jobs, but the product is focused more heavily on developers because the audience of Stack Overflow is far, far bigger.

Comment: That's because there are perhaps two orders of magnitude more developers than sysadmins. I do agree with the sentiment, though; I really _don't_ want to see programming jobs, even if I _can_ write a program.

Comment: @ShaneMadden : I forgot to say non local jobs *(systems ones are rarely advertised)*.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : If you agree with the sentiment, please upvote this question *(as this site is dedicated to professional)*. Remember jobs can be at least sorted.

Comment: @ShaneMadden : It seems [things changed](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1078/203649).

Comment: @user2284570 That post you're referencing is from 2011, and is way, way older than the current targeting setup, which was introduced this year. When an employer lists a job, they can flag it as being a sysadmin job, which will target it at Server Fault users.  Again, your Stack Overflow activity (10x the rep you have here, so it's a reasonable assumption for the system to make that you're a developer and not a sysadmin) and lack of local sysadmin jobs are the reason you're seeing programming jobs, not neglect of the sysadmin community in the careers product.

Comment: @ShaneMadden do you mean really flag, or using the sysadmin tag *(which near all sysadmin jobs aren’t using)* ?

Comment: @user2284570 No. When employers create a listing, they have drop-downs asking them what type of role it is (front end web developer? mobile developer? system administrator?), and technologies they use (programming languages, OS platforms), in addition to the tag set that you can see.